# Can't compile Fortran modules: Undefined symbol _main

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I've been trying lately to use libraries in Fotran, but I kept on getting this error message

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

which I cound't find any specific solution to it. In this case, I was working with some libraries that I built myself (this problem happened with static and shared libraries) from simples modules I wrote for purposses of tests.

I decided to try only the modules then, and I kept getting the same error message regardes of the module I used. I would like to know if someone can help me on telling if I am using incorrect syntax. Here is the module

```
module modulo1

IMPLICIT NONE

real, parameter:: pi=3.1415

end module modulo1
```

This is the main

```
program teste

use modulo1

IMPLICIT NONE

real :: r = 2

write (*,*) 'Área: ', pi*r**2

end program teste
```

These were the commands I used for compiling

```
gfortran -c modulo1.f90
gfortran -c teste.f90
gfortran -o teste.o modulo1.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation is broken.  The command

```
gfortran -o teste.o modulo1.o
```

tells `gfortran` to create an executable called `teste.o` from the object file called `modulo1.o`.  Since that module file doesn't contain a `program` the compiler can't find an entry point for the executable it is trying to build.  The argument to the `-o` option is the name of the executable to build.

You probably ought to replace that statement with something like

```
gfortran -o test teste.o modulo1.o
```

which will build an executable called `test`.

In the longer run learn how to use `make` or another build system.