# Error when compiling with mpifort

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have downloaded OpenMPI, but after trying to run a simple parallelized Hello world program I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess there is a problem with the compiler because I struggled quite a lot to install OpenMPI.
In order to get that error I typed from the terminal:

```
mpifort -o hello.f90
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: recreate `hello.f90` and then `mpifort -o hello hello.f90`

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081298/cant-compile-fortran-modules-undefined-symbol-main but since the answer to that hasn't been accepted I can't dupe-hammer this one.